# Why does OpenGL double-buffering seem to be inconsistent performance-wise?

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, frame-rate, double-buffering

I'm making a simple graphical app on OSX. I just started monitoring the frame rate by checking the difference in system time between frames. It seems to be hanging a bit every few frames.

The app runs on an NSTimer object, currently set to 200 fps (5 ms frames). To make sure it wasn't just my main code being slow, I commented out the entire main loop, except for [self.context flushBuffer]; (and of course the frame-rate sampling code). Even repeating this single call is causing it to hang for several frames at a time. Here is an example of my console output:

```
4
5
6
10
5
5
5
4
6
10
5
5
5
5
5
5
20
4
5
6
20
5
5
5
```

This is the time in milliseconds between each loop iteration. At 200 fps, it should be about 5 ms for each frame, but it repeatedly hangs for 10, 15, or even 20 ms. Vsyncing is disabled, as you can see in my -initOpenGL function.

```
-(void)initOpenGL{
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[] = {NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer, 0};
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes: attributes];
    self.context = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
    [self.context setView:[self.window contentView]];
    [self.context makeCurrentContext];

    //Disable Vsync
    int temp = 0;
    [self.context setValues: &temp forParameter: NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];

    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, -1, 100);

    //Flip all textures right side up
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }
```

**Edit, new information: I can confirm that this has something to do with double-buffering vs single. When I initialize the NSOpenGLPixelFormat without the DoubleBuffer attribute, it runs perfectly at 200 fps. Whereas with that attribute, I continue to get the stuttering.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing the actual rendering code (which wasn't posted), one very possible cause is that using a `NSTimer` for frame rate control in the first place isn't such a great idea. Refer to the documentation (emphasis added):

> A timer is **not a real-time mechanism**; it fires only when one of the run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the **effective resolution** of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of **50-100 milliseconds**.

Thus, the expectation to use a timer for something like 5 milliseconds is fundamentally flawed.

In addition to that, there may be other effects (process scheduling, texture uploads and stalls in OpenGL, etc.) that will make frame times not 100% constant. Though the jitter caused by these will usually be on a much smaller scale.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have always been under the impression that NSTimer was the standard for frame-rate control on Apple devices; it seems to be used more often than anything else. What would be a better alternative? Also, I omitted the rendering code because it seems to be irrelevant to the problem. Like I said, this is occurring even when everything is commented out, and I'm literally only calling [context flushBuffer];. So it seems logical that we can rule out anything in my  code (unless I improperly initialized something in OpenGL).

Comment: I also just narrowed it down a little more; read the edit on the OP.

Comment: The standard for frame-rate control on Apple as well as any other platform I know is to enable v-sync. Timers (or even worse, sleeping) are not and have never been "standard" because of their rather unpredictable non-realtime nature (on non-RT operating systems such as e.g. OSX). Also, using a timer is unwise because two distinct clocks (app timer and v-sync) will eventually always get out of sync (think indicator lights on two cars!). I cannot tell why turning off double buffering seems to "work" better, but it doesn't change the fact that the approach is flawed.

Comment: Thanks guys, after reading [the Run Loop reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html), I realize the actual purpose of NSTimer, and that I should just use a while loop and control the timing myself. You'd be surprised at how many people I've seen misusing timers that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good synchro on OSX, you should a CoreVideo DisplayLink. It is a callback called at each screen vertical refresh, so if your screen is at 60 FPS, this callback will be called (in a separated thread, be carefull with OpenGL threading) 60 times per second, and that's what should trigger an OpenGL refresh.